# SQL SERVER - Concat NULL Numeric Column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table

```
CREATE TABLE [name].[tblRange] 
(
  [RangeId_PK] numeric(6, 0) IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
  [Lower] numeric(18, 2) NOT NULL,
  [Upper] numeric(18, 2) NULL
)
```

I want to concat Lower and Upper but it always give me NULL if Upper contain NULL value.

This is my query:

```
SELECT CAST(Lower AS VARCHAR(50)) + '-' + CAST(Upper AS VARCHAR(50))
FROM name.tblRange
```

I can't use the following query because it will give this error (`SQL Server Database Error: Error converting data type varchar to numeric.`)

```
SELECT CAST(Lower AS VARCHAR(50)) + '-' + CAST(ISNULL(Upper, '') AS VARCHAR(50))
FROM name.tblRange
```

*Please note that I can't use `ISNULL(Upper, 0)` because that is a upper limit (can't be 0).*

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: what will be your upper limit if it contains NULL value?

Comment: put empty to that ISNULL(Upper, '') or NULL ISNULL(Upper, 'NULL') or what ever u want. It must not only be 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the ISNULL gets two different types as arguments. Switch the CAST and ISNULL statements:

```
SELECT CAST(Lower AS VARCHAR(50)) + '-' + ISNULL(CAST(Upper AS VARCHAR(50)), '') FROM name.tblRange
```

Answer (score 3):

You were far on the right way by using `isnull`.

You can use something like this to use the correct data types:

This one shows `0`, `999` as values when `lower` and `upper` are `null`:

```
SELECT cast(isnull(Lower, 0) AS VARCHAR(50))
       + '-'
       + cast(isnull(Upper, 999) AS VARCHAR(50))
FROM name.tblRange
```

Or this one shows only the dash when `lower` and upper are `null`:

```
SELECT isnull(cast(Lower AS VARCHAR(50)), '')
       + '-'
       + isnull(cast(Upper AS VARCHAR(50)), '')
FROM name.tblRange
```